# Using FMDB in a singleton, is better FMDatabase or FMDatabaseQueue

Tags: ios, objective-c, fmdb

i want create 3 or more different singleton to handle different store scenario in my app using [FMDB](https://github.com/ccgus/fmdb), an example of a singleton is this:

.h

```
@interface MyManager : NSObject

+ (id)sharedManager;
- (BOOL)isChecked:(int)id_product;

@end
```

.m

```
    @implementation MyManager

    @synthesize someProperty;

    #pragma mark Singleton Methods

    + (id)sharedManager {
        static MyManager *sharedMyManager = nil;
        static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
        dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
            sharedMyManager = [[self alloc] init];
        });
        return sharedMyManager;
    }

    - (id)init {
      if (self = [super init]) {
          self.databaseQueue = [FMDatabaseQueue databaseQueueWithPath:databasePath]; //or FMDatabase
      }
      return self;
    }

- (BOOL)isChecked:(int)id_product
{
    BOOL isChecked = NO;

    [self.databaseQueue inDatabase:^(FMDatabase *db) {

        FMResultSet *product_query = [db executeQuery:@"SELECT isChecked FROM products WHERE id = ?",[NSNumber numberWithInt:id_product]];

        while ([product_query next]) {

            if ([product_query boolForColumn:@"isChecked"] == 1) {
                isChecked = YES;
            } else {
                isChecked = NO;
            }
        }
    }];

    return isChecked;
}

    @end
```

So my question is, can i create 3 or more singleton like this that use a `FMDatabaseQueue` or a `FMDatabase` defined as a class property for the class, and is better using `FMDatabaseQueue` or `FMDatabase`?

Comment: If it's a singleton you cannot "create 3 or more". Singleton means you can create only one.

Comment: three different singleton class, for example, MyManager1, MyManager2, MyManager3 with three different .h and .m file...can i do it?

Comment: Why not? Did you try it and it failed? What's the problem?

Comment: no i haven't tried, my question is not about singleton is about using it with FMDatabaseQueue or FMDatabase, and which of the two of them is better in this singleton implementation

Comment: It depends what you're doing, doesn't it? The fmdb docs are clear on what FMDatabaseQueue is for. If you need it you need it. If you don't you don't. I still don't see what the question is.

Comment: i have to do different operation with the database like query, update, insert, delete, and i have to call these singleton in NSOperation or when a user press a simple button in the UI, so my question is what is the best to use, FMDatabaseQueue or FMDatabase. Because if i use a FMDatabase i have to open and close it every time i make an operation, instead with fmdatabasequeue i haven't, i doesn't know if i explained well my question

Comment: No, you didn't explain it at all. You have given no information that would help anyone else decide if you need FMDatabase or FMDatabaseQueue. And which one you need has nothing to do with the whole "singleton" thing! It's completely irrelevant. - You should not have multiple FMDatabaseQueue objects, though, so your "multiple singleton" idea would make no sense.

Comment: Use FMDatabaseQueue if you might possibly be trying to access the object from multiple threads. Only use FMDarabase if you're absolutely confident that only one thread will be interfacing with the object.

Comment: @matt So you just give me an answer to my question :) can you exaplain it now? Why i can't have multiple fmdatabasequeue object in different singleton class?

Comment: Regarding the multiple singleton question, that's very strange, but if they're not the same database file, you could theoretically do that.

Comment: @Rob so my idea of use different singleton with fmdatabasequeue is possibile?

Comment: @rob, ok i think i can use only one singleton, the idea of use different singleton was only to make code more readable, and divide the operation for type

Comment: "Why i can't have multiple fmdatabasequeue object in different singleton class"? Because that's the way fmdb is written. You are allowed to have only one FMDatabaseQueue. It must, itself, be a singleton. But if you define "3 or more singleton" the way _you_ have defined them, it will not be a singleton.

Comment: @Rob, what you mean with: "Only use FMDarabase if you're absolutely confident that only one thread will be interfacing with the object.", with object you mean with the database?

Comment: @Piero You said "Because if i use a FMDatabase i have to open and close it every time i make an operation ..." No, that's not true. You can open a `FMDatabase` instance once and leave it open. In fact, I would generally advise that, rather than continuously opening and closing it. The only difference between `FMDatabase` and `FMDatabaseQueue` is that the latter will coordinate calls that happen to take place from multiple threads whereas the former will not.

Comment: @Piero You asked, "with object, you mean with the database?" I mean your individual singleton objects with have instantiated their own `FMDatabase`/`FMDatabaseQueue` objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few thoughts:

1. You theoretically can have three different classes of singleton objects, each with its own `FMDatabase`/`FMDatabaseQueue` instance.

   Whether you should do this is a completely different question. Having three, without some very compelling argument for that, suggests some serious code smell.
2. Make sure that none of those three instances are trying to access the same database file, or else you defeat the entire purpose of `FMDatabaseQueue`. This three instance model is only plausible if you're dealing with three different database files (and even then, it seems like a curious design).

   You say "i think i can use only one singleton, the idea of use different singleton was only to make code more readable, and divide the operation for type."

   That is, absolutely, not an argument for three singleton classes. you should only have one.
3. In terms of `FMDatabase` vs. `FMDatabaseQueue`, the latter enables you to enjoy multithreaded access, so I would lean towards that. Using `FMDatabase` offers no significant advantages, but introduces limitations unnecessarily.

   The whole purpose of `FMDatabaseQueue` is to manage database contention when you have multiple threads accessing the same database. So if you know, with absolute certainty, that you'll never access `FMDatabase` object from different threads, then you could use `FMDatabase`.

   But why paint yourself into a corner like that? Just use `FMDatabaseQueue` and then you don't have to worry about it. It works fine if used from single thread and saves you from many headaches if you happen to use it from multiple threads (e.g. you use your instances from GCD blocks, inside completion handlers for asynchronous methods, etc.).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, i have the last question, using the fmdatabasequeue stop the flow of the execution until the database operation has finished or make it in a different thread? For example i make you a simple scenario, i have a singleton with the fmdatabasequeue like i show you in the code of the question, in this singleton i have two method one to insert rows in the database and one to query rows, the no have an nsoperation that call the singleton to perform a insert request and then query the database, so my question is, in the query request i can see the rows i have insert

Comment: In the insert request, or there is a chance that haven't inserted it yet? So in a few word when i call the insert method the flow in the nsoperation stop until the insert method finish or not?

Comment: `FMDatabaseQueue` is just a custom serial queue. So, if it has started the `insert`, it won't do the second operation, the `select`, until the `insert` is done.

Comment: Ok, but the operation of the fmdatabasequeue are in a Black so the flow of the execution continue right?

Comment: `FMDatabaseQueue` uses blocks, but you should not assume that it run asynchronously, because, in fact, it runs synchronously (i.e. the calling thread will wait until `FMDatabaseQueue` finishes).

Comment: @NSNoob That error you describe is not a result of different threads trying to interact with the same database. The problem is that you have a thread that is calling `inDatabase` or `inTransaction` and that inside that block, you're calling some method that is trying to call `inDatabase` or `inTransaction` again! If you look at the stack trace after you get this error (press command+6 in Xcode), you can see the the complete path and you can track it back and you'll see two calls to `inDatabase`/`inTransaction` in the same stack trace.

Comment: @Rob Thanks a lot for your help mate. Sorry for the out-of-blue comments,  I did not have enough data about it to qualify for a suitable question so I didn't create a new post. Cheers again!